# Terraform foreach on azure nics (map)

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to convert those variables in main.tf to terraform.tfvars and variables.tf ( declarer the variables in terraform.tfvars and variables.tf ).

i want to create map ( map is required because I'm using for each ) using couple of network interfaces name and virtual machine names and loop on them when creating new vms .

**main.tf**

here i create the variables in the main.tf but as i wrote i want to declarer them in the variables.tf file

```
variable "nics" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {

    nic3 = {
      name = "ubuntutest3"
    }

    nic4 = {
      name = "ubuntutest4"
    }
  }
}

variable "vms" {
  description = "Virtual Machines"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    vm3 = {
      name = "ubuntutest3"
      size = "Standard_DS1_v2"
      nic  = "nic3"
    }
    vm4 = {
      name = "ubuntutest4"
      size = "Standard_DS1_v2"
      nic  = "nic4"
    }
  }
}

// VNICs
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  for_each            = var.nics
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${each.value.name}-conf"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

and when I'm creating vms there is line for

```
  network_interface_ids            = [azurerm_network_interface.nics[each.value.nic].id, ]
```

when i tried to declarer those variables in variable.tf file and terraform.tfvars i got error massage

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 259, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vms":
│  259:   network_interface_ids            = [azurerm_network_interface.nics[each.value.nic].id, ]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.nics is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.value.nic is "network_interface_2"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

how should i declarer on vm names and nic names in variables.tf and create the names i want to use in terraform.tfvars and use them I'm main.tf ?

**EDITED**

I tried like this

**terraform.tfvars**

```
nics = {
  nic_names = ["nic2,nic3"]
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "nics" {
  type = object({
    nic_names = list(string)
  })
}
```

got error

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 272, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics":
│  272:   name                = each.value.nic_names
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is list of string with 1 element
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Comment: It seems it's not the same code you are providing. The variable must have different values assigned compared to the default ones. Is there a `.tfvars` file that has the value for the variable defined?

Comment: Your right , well the question is just how can i declarer the variables of nics and vms in varriables.tf then assign them the values in terraform.tfvars and use them in the main.tf

Comment: Well, assign them the same way you did assign the value to the `nics` variable. Define the variable value in `terraform.tfvars` and set the `nic` key of the `vms` variable to map to the values you have defined, i.e., `nic = "network_interface_2"` and I'm guessing `nic = "network_interface_3"` or it should be 1 and 2 or whatever.

Comment: Yes i tried , did not work for me

Comment: Then please add all the relevant code to the question, including the variable value assignment.

Comment: Where is `network_interface_2` coming from then?

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with tfvars used instead of variables. The error states explicitly that when you create a VM, `each.value.nic` at this particular iteration is `network_interface_2`, while in `nics` map you only have keys `nic3` and `nic4`.

As for the second part, you have probably wanted to type:

```
nic_names = ["nic2","nic3"]
```

instead of:

```
nic_names = ["nic2,nic3"]
```

The second is only one string in a list, the first is two element-list.

**EDIT**

To show directly how @ITBYD should set his files into working solution:

terraform.tfvars:

```
nics = {
  nic_names = ["nic2","nic3"]
}
```

main.tfvars:

```
variable "nics" {
  type = object({
    nic_names = list(string)
  })
}

# [...]

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  for_each            = toset(var.nics["nic_names"])
  name                = each.value
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${each.value}-conf"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

But I would not use list, only map instead just like I wrote earlier.

Comment: Im getting error 

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 272, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics":
│  272:   name                = each.value.nic_names
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.

Comment: I used it like this ---> 

name                = each.value.nic_names

Comment: that's because your terraform.tfvars are nothing like the map you had in the first place. Now each.value is already a list. I think you should declare the map in tfvars just like you had it in variables  ( nics = { nic_names = { name = "1" } }

Comment: getting error ---> │ The given value is not suitable for var.nics declared at varibels.tf:103,1-16: attribute "nic_names": list of string required.

Comment: I have edited the answer to correct your code for you, but I got a feeling you misunderstand my point completely. I showed you what the first error was and then showed you what the second error was, and then told you what you should change. If you insist on correcting the code above, be my guest, but it is not the way it should be corrected.